# How to get Select's text from jqGrid column with inline editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I need to get the text and value of a cell in jqGrid that is of `edittype='select'`

Here's my colModel

```
{ name: 'ResponsibleId', editable: true, width: 140, sortable: false, formatter: 'select', edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: ResponsibleList } }
```

I'm using inline editing and free-jqgrid v4.9.0

When I run `var respId = $(gridId).jqGrid('getCell', row_id, "ResponsibleId");`

It gives me the right value of the item but I need the text as well.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to get selected option directly. You need only know that jqGrid assign `id` on editable fields based on the rule: `rowid + "_" + columnName`. So the code which you need will be

```
var $option = $("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(row_id) + "_ResponsibleId option").filter(":selected");
```

The `$option.text()` will get you the text and `$option.val()` gets you the value of currently selected option.

**UPDATE:** If you need to get **the text** of the cell which uses `formatter: "select"` you can do for example the following:

```
var $grid = $(gridId),
    $tr = $grid.jqGrid("getGridRowById", row_id),
    iCol = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "iColByName").ResponsibleId, // or [colname]
    $tdData = $.jgrid.getDataFieldOfCell.call($grid[0], $tr, iCol);

alert($tdData.text());
```

`$tdData` will get you jQuery wrapper to `<td>` or some internal `<span>` of `<td>` which holds the data which you require. `$tdData.text()` gets you the text from the cell. If the name of column you have in the variable (in `colName` for example) then you should use `[colName]` instead of `.ResponsibleId`.

Comment: Thanks for support @Oleg, but this works when the row is in editmode. I need the text when the row is in Read mode as well.

Comment: @Imran: see **UPDATED** part of my answer.